# Error while migrating from UIWebView to WKWebView for Cordova app

Tags: angular, cordova, wkwebview

Recently we are trying to migrate the iOS apps (Angular + Cordova) to the WKWebView, however after adding the
changes the app is stuck with a warning "[Warning] Unhandled Navigation Error:  (cordova.js, line 1540)"
the app works properly with the UIWebView and android.
There is no stack trace available for the stack trace. Has anyone else faced this issue?

UPDATE: Please find additional details.

For the migration, I have followed instruction from [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/howto/2020/03/18/wkwebviewonly.html)

> error screenshot:
> [image]

> config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>CordovaApp</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
        <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^4.0.0" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="^1.2.1" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.3" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.2" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.2" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.1.0" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions" spec="^1.2.0">
            <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="This app needs camera access" />
            <variable name="MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="This app needs microphone access" />
            <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="This app needs write-access to photo library" />
            <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="This app needs read/write-access photo library access" />
        </plugin>
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.7.1" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr" spec="^2.1.4" />
        <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
        </feature>
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AboutusComponent } from './aboutus/aboutus.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
import { DefaultComponent } from './default/default.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { HttpService } from './services/http.service';
import { KeycloakService } from './services/keycloak.service';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './services/token.interceptor';
export function kcFactory(keycloakService: KeycloakService) {
  return () => keycloakService.init();
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, AboutusComponent, ErrorComponent, DefaultComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    HttpService,
    AuthGuard,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: kcFactory,
      deps: [KeycloakService],
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CONCERT_URLS as URLS } from './constants/urls';
import { HttpService } from './services/http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public title = 'Ang';

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService, private router: Router) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAccountDetails();
  }

  getAccountDetails() {
    const allAccounts = this.httpService
      .getData(URLS.ACCOUNT.GET.byPageAndSize(), true, {})
      .subscribe((accountDetails: any) => {
        console.log(accountDetails);
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
      });
  }
}
```

> app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutusComponent } from './aboutus/aboutus.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
import { DefaultComponent } from './default/default.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'aboutus',
    component: AboutusComponent,
  },

  {
    path: 'default',
    component: DefaultComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'default',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: ErrorComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

NOTE: the app is working normally on Android platform and as a web application with this same codebase.

Comment: There are an assortment of reasons that could cause you to run into this problem. Id suggest providing your config xml, top level app module and app component code as well as to describe in detail how you went about the upgrade.

Comment: @DevMike I have added the details and updated the question.